# Two methods for building and displaying rooms in a text RPG game using python

Tags: python, text

I'm very inexperienced and found these two methods for implementing rooms in an rpg game id like to create.  Id just like some input on which method is superior to the other.  I'm just wondering what headaches I may run into with each.  They both seem to have something going for them.  I'm just not sure about using functions this way, I couldn't find a way to do this with classes.  Any input would be great, thank you.

I prefer how this one prints out.

```
   def lobby():
    #exits
    N = 'n[lounge]'
    S = 's[airlock]'
    E = 'e[wall]'
    W = 'w[wall]'
    #room description
    print('A quiet and empty lobby')
    print('There is a dusty desk in front of a bad painting.')
    print('exits-', N, S, E, W)
    d = input('go which direction?')
    if d == 'n':
        lounge()
    else:
        wall()
def wall():
    print('You cant go that way')
        #room function
def lounge():
    global lounge_action
    N = 'n[wall]'
    S = 's[lobby]'
    E = 'e[wall]'
    W = 'w[wall]'
    #Room description
    print('A few people are having drinks here.')
    #Things in the room
    print('The bartender says "Hello".')
    print('exits-', N, S, E, W)
    d = input('go which direction?')
    if d == 's':
        lobby()
    else:
        wall()
def start():
    lobby()

d = 's'
while d != 'quit':
    start()
```

And this is the other option ive seen.

```
rooms = {
'lobby': {
        'name': 'an empty lobby',
        'north': 'lounge',
        'south': 'airlock',
        'text': 'There is an empty desk in the room.'
                'The floors are made of cold metal.' },
'lounge': {
        'name': 'a quiet lounge',
        'south': 'lobby',
        'text': 'The bartender asks what you want.'},
'airlock':{
    'name': 'a cold landing pad',
    'north': 'lobby',
    'text': 'there is a ship parked here'
}

        }
directions = ['north', 'south', 'east', 'west']
current_room = rooms['lobby']
d = 'lobby'

while d != 'quit':
    print(current_room)
    d = input('\nWhat do you do?')
    if d in directions:
        if d in current_room:
            current_room = rooms[current_room[d]]
        else:
            print('Cant go that way')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"I couldn't find a way to do this with classes."

The way you could do this with a class (and a better solution IMHO) is to use the class to create a template for information used in each location, then a class for each location.

```
class Room:
    def __init__(self, name, exits, description):
        self.name = name
        self.exits = exits
        self.description = description

class Lobby(Room):
    def __init__(self):
        exit_list = {"north":Lounge, "south":Airlock}
        super().__init__("an empty lobby", exit_list, "There is an empty desk in the room.\nThe floors are made of cold metal.")

class Lounge(Room):
    def __init__(self):
        exit_list = {"south":Lobby}
        super().__init__("a quiet lounge", exit_list, "The bartender asks what you want.")

class Airlock(Room):
    def __init__(self):
        exit_list = {"north":Lobby}
        super().__init__("a cold landing pad", exit_list, "There is a ship parked here")
```

Then, to modify the code you have in the second example to implement this:

```
def main():
    current_room = Lobby()
    d = ""
    while d != 'quit':
        print(current_room.name)
        d = input('\nWhich way do you want to go?\n')
        if d in current_room.exits:
            current_room = current_room.exits[d]()
        else:
            print('Cant go that way')
```

Note: The 'exit_list' variable is a dictionary, but I took artistic license.

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand from your question is that you would like to know what implementation of a basic RPG is 'better'. Of course better is something subjective, but I would prefer the second implementation.

The way they separate the code from the data of the rooms is nicely done. This makes it easier to expand your project and would even make it possible to load a level from an external source in the future as long as your code captures all edge cases.

Something you could improve yourself is the lack of printing the messages about the environment. You could add the functionality to print an explanation of the room that someone just entered, and it's lacking the description of which direction someone can walk towards.

Only thing I would change in the way it's currently stored is moving all directions into a new dict called directions. This would make it easier to print the possible directions for a user.

If you want to take this project to the next level you would go ahead and create a class called Room with certain general functionality. And you would go ahead and create new classes for each separate room to add special functionalities to the game.

In case you prefer to follow a tutorial, checkout this awesome [guide](https://letstalkdata.com/2014/08/how-to-write-a-text-adventure-in-python-part-1-items-and-enemies/)!